# Trying to save an array into UserDefaults

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, userdefaults

In my code, data is an array of format [String : Any], I'm trying to store it in userdefaults

```
 let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: data)
                userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "data")
                userDefaults.synchronize()
```

but I get this error:

```
   -[Features encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I dont think error you posted has anything to do with the code you posted, there must be other code which is causing this error

Comment: you were right, I edited the post with the correct error

Comment: Is it an array of Features objects? You can only store arrays of strings, numbers, Date objects, and Data objects in the user's defaults database. I think you should conform your datatype to Codable and use PropertyListEncoder

Comment: Show your object  data declaration and it’s contents

Comment: Show your Feature object declaration. Does it conform to NSCoding or NSSecureCoding?

Answer (score 0):

You can only store  several types of objects in UserDefaults like Int, String, Float, Double, Bool, URL, Data or collection of these types. However according to apple:

> If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically
> archive it to create an instance of NSData.

Luckily Apple released `Codable` so any class or struct conforming to Codable can be converted to and from Data.

First conform your dataModel to `Codable`

```
struct Features : Codable {
   var feature1:String?
   var feature2:String?
}
```

then after you create you objects and add them to the array

```
let feature1 = Features(feature1: "awesome", feature2: "World")
let feature2 = Features(feature1: "Hello", feature2: "World")    
arrayOfFeatures = [feature1,feature2]
```

you can use save them like this:

```
 func saveInUserDefault(with arrayOfFeatures:[Features]){
        do{
    UserDefaults.standard.set(try PropertyListEncoder().encode(arrayOfFeatures), forKey: "data")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

and get them with like this:

```
func getDataFromArray(){
        if let savedData: Data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "data"){
            do
           {
            arrayOfFeatures = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Features].self, from: savedData)
            for feature in arrayOfFeatures
            {
                print(feature.feature1)
                print(feature.feature2)
            }
           }
            catch
            {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    saveInUserDefault(with: arrayOfFeatures)
```